# Find the sum:$\lfloor\frac{3^{20}+1}{2}\rfloor+\lfloor\frac{3^{20}+2}{4}\rfloor+\lfloor\frac{3^{20}+4}{8}\rfloor+\cdots$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Find the sum:

$$\left\lfloor\frac{3^{20}+1}{2}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac{3^{20}+2}{4}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac{3^{20}+4}{8}\right\rfloor+\cdots$$

I know the $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left\lfloor\dfrac{3^{20}+2^{n-1}}{2^n}\right\rfloor$, but now what?

Answer (score 3):

The sequence $ \left(\left\lfloor\frac{3^{20}+2^{n-1}}{2^{n}}\right\rfloor\right)_{n}=\left(\left\lfloor\frac{3^{20}}{2^{n}}+\frac{1}{2}\right\rfloor\right)_{n} $ has a finite support : $ \left(\forall n\geq 33\right),\ \frac{3^{20}}{2^{n}}+\frac{1}{2}\in\left[0,1\right[ $, meaning : $$ \left(\forall n\geq 33\right),\ \left\lfloor\frac{3^{20}+2^{n-1}}{2^{n}}\right\rfloor=0 $$

Thus, $$ \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}{\left\lfloor\frac{3^{20}+2^{n-1}}{2^{n}}\right\rfloor}=\sum_{n=1}^{32}{\left\lfloor\frac{3^{20}+2^{n-1}}{2^{n}}\right\rfloor}=3486784401 $$

Comment: FYI Your final answer is just $3^{20}$. So there's something more to it than just tedious/computer calculation over finitely many terms.

Comment: @Calvin Lin True, I will try soon to prove the following result which is more general : $$ \left(\forall m\in\mathbb{N}\right),\ \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}{\left\lfloor\frac{m+2^{n-1}}{2^{n}}\right\rfloor}=m $$, you had already proven it below, but I will try to do it without induction.

Comment: It can also be done directly (which was how I was approaching the $3^{20}$ case), by relating $ \lfloor \ldots \rfloor$ to the base 2 representation. It is well known that $ \sum \lfloor \frac{n}{2^k} \rfloor$ is equal to $n$ minus the number of 1's in the base 2 representation. We're doing something similar here.

Comment: Right. Thank you @Calvin Lin :)

Answer (score 1):

This claim can be observed by testing small cases of $n$.
In fact, the proof also follows from looking at these small cases.
So, I encourage you to look at the small cases first, before reading on.

---

**Claim:** For all $n \in \mathbb{N}$,

$$ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \lfloor \frac{ n } { 2^k } + \frac{1}{2} \rfloor = n $$

Proof: By induction.
Base case $ n = 1$ is obvious.

Let $ n + 1 = 2^l \times m$, where $m $ is an odd integer.

Notice that $ \lfloor \frac{ n +1 } { 2^k } + \frac{1}{2} \rfloor = \lfloor \frac{ n } { 2^k } + \frac{1}{2} \rfloor + 1$ iff $ \frac{ n+ 1 + 2^{k-1}}{2^k} $ is an integer.

> This occurs only when $ k-1 = l$. (Prove it! Deal with $k-1 < l, k-1 = l, k-1 > l$ separately.)
>  For all other cases, we have $ \lfloor \frac{ n +1 } { 2^k } + \frac{1}{2} \rfloor = \lfloor \frac{ n } { 2^k } + \frac{1}{2} \rfloor $.

Hence, the LHS sum increases by exactly 1 each time, namely when $k-1 = l$.
So the RHS increases by exactly 1 each time.
This completes the induction.

Comment: I am intrigued by your answer.  I **request** that you edit your answer as if you were presenting a **complete solution to a 16 year old.**

Comment: Given that OP has shown no work, I'm going to decline. I've been scolded numerous times for giving out complete solutions on MSE in such a scenario.

Comment: I can make a much stronger claim, so I've now included details.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with and upvoted Calvin Lin's answer.  My *answer*:
(1) Proves a related assertion that he made in one of his comments on this webpage.
(2) Discusses/contrasts the proof in his answer with my proof.

(1) To Prove: $\;\forall \;n \,\in \,\mathbb{Z^+}\;\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \;\left\lfloor \frac{n}{2^k}\right\rfloor
\;=\; $
$n\;$ minus the # of 1's in the base 2 representation of $n.$

By inspection it is true for $n=1.$  Suppose it is true for $n=N.$ 
Let $\;\alpha \;\equiv\;$ the largest exponent such that 
$\;2^{\alpha} \;\leq\; N.$ 
Let $\;f(N) \;\equiv\;$ the #1's in the base 2 representation of $N.$ 
Let $\;s(N) \;\equiv\; \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \;\left\lfloor \frac{N}{2^k}\right\rfloor.$

Then:
a. $\;s(N) \;= \;\left\lfloor \frac{N}{2^1}\right\rfloor \;+
\;\left\lfloor \frac{N}{2^2}\right\rfloor \;+
\;\left\lfloor \frac{N}{2^3}\right\rfloor \;+
\;\cdots \;+
\;\left\lfloor \frac{N}{2^{\alpha}}\right\rfloor.$ 
b. By assumption, $\;N - f(N) = s(N).$

Let $\;M = 2N \;\Rightarrow$ 
c. $\;2^{(\alpha + 1)} \;\leq\; M \;<\; 2^{(\alpha + 2)}.$ 
d. For $\;1 \leq k \leq \alpha,$ 
$\;\frac{M}{2^{(k+1)}} \;=\; \frac{N}{2^{k}} \;\Rightarrow$
$\;\left\lfloor \frac{M}{2^{(k+1)}}\right\rfloor \;=\;$
$\;\left\lfloor \frac{N}{2^{k}}\right\rfloor.$ 
e. $\;\left\lfloor \frac{M}{2^1}\right\rfloor \;=\; N.$ 
f. $\;f(M) = f(N).$

Therefore, $\;s(M) = s(N) + 
\left\lfloor \frac{M}{2^1}\right\rfloor
\;=\; s(N) + N \;=\; 2N - f(N) \;=\; M - f(M).$

$\therefore\;$ If the conjecture is true for $N$,
then the conjecture is true for $2N$.

Suppose that the conjecture is true for a specific even number of form $2N$. Then:
g. By assumption, $\;(2N) - f(2N) = s(2N).$ 
h. $\;s(2N+1) \;=\;s(2N).$ 
i. Since $(2N+1)$ has the same # of 1's in its base 2 representation as $(2N)$ except that $(2N+1)$ also has a 1 in the $2^0$ slot, $f(2N+1) = f(2N) + 1.$

Therefore, $\;s(2N+1) \;=\; s(2N) \;=\; (2N) - f(2N)
\;=\; (2N+1) - f(2N+1).$

$\therefore\;$ If the conjecture is true for $(2N)$,
then the conjecture is true for $(2N+1)$.

Thus, the conjecture is true for 1 $\;\Rightarrow\;$
the conjecture is true for 2,3 $\;\Rightarrow\;$ 
the conjecture is true for 4 through 7 $\;\Rightarrow\;$ 
the conjecture is true for 8 through 15 $\;\Rightarrow\;$ 
$\cdots$

(2) His proof and mine both avoided trying to find an **elegant direct** proof and instead opted for induction.  It is unclear whether elegant direct proofs exist for either or both conjectures.

Further, with his conjecture involving 
$\;\left\lfloor \frac{n}{2^k} + \frac{1}{2} \right\rfloor$, 
his proof showed that if the conjecture is true for $N$ then the conjecture is true for $N+1.$

With my conjecture involving the # of digits in the base 2 representation of $N$,
my proof showed that if the conjecture is true for $N$ then the conjecture is true for both $2N$ and $(2N+1).$

$\underline{\textbf{Addendum}}$

Based on Calvin Lin's subsequent comment, I discovered more elegant proofs for the two conjectures, which bypassed using induction.  It seems worthwhile to show the proofs and simultaneously show the connection between the two conjectures.

Let the base 2 representation of $n$ be given by 
$n = 2^{a_1} + 2^{a_2} + \cdots + 2^{a_m},$ 
where $\;a_1, a_2, \cdots, a_m \,\in \,\mathbb{Z}\;$ and
$\;0 \leq a_1 < a_2 < \cdots < a_m.$

For $\;r \,\in \,\{ \,1, \,2, \,\cdots, \,m \} \;$ 
let $\;f(r) = 2^{a_r} + 2^{a_{[r+1]}} + \cdots + 2^{a_m} 
\;\Rightarrow \;$ 
[for example] $\;f(1) = n\;$ and $\;f(m) = 2^{a_m}.$

$\underline{\text{Part 1:  To Prove} 
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \,\left\lfloor \dfrac{n}{2^k} \right\rfloor = (n - m)}$

Lemma 1 : $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{a_r} \,\dfrac{2^{a_r}}{2^k} 
= 2^{a_r} - 1.$

Proof: $\;\dfrac{2^{a_r}}{2^1} \;+\;
\dfrac{2^{a_r}}{2^2} \;+\;
\cdots \;+\;
\dfrac{2^{a_r}}{2^{a_r}} 
\;=\;
2^{(a_r - 1)} \;+\; 2^{(a_r - 2)} \;+\; \cdots + 1 \;=\; 2^{a_r} - 1.$

For $\;k \leq a_1, \;2^k \,| \,f(1) \;\Rightarrow\;
\left\lfloor \dfrac{f(1)}{2^k} \right\rfloor \;= \; \dfrac{f(1)}{2^k}.\;\;$
Thus, $\displaystyle\;\sum_{k=1}^{a_1} \left\lfloor \dfrac{f(1)}{2^k} \right\rfloor
\;=\; \sum_{k=1}^{a_1} \dfrac{f(1)}{2^k}.$

For $\;t \,\in \,\{ \,1, \,2, \,\cdots, \,(m-1) \,\}\;$ and
$\;a_t < k \leq a_{(t+1)},$

$2^k \,| \,f(t+1)\;$ and $\;f(1) - f(t+1) < 2^k
\;\Rightarrow 
\left\lfloor \dfrac{f(1)}{2^k} \right\rfloor \;= \; \dfrac{f(t+1)}{2^k}.\;\;$

Thus, $\displaystyle\;\sum_{k = (a_t \;+\; 1)}^{a_{[t + 1]}} \left\lfloor \dfrac{f(1)}{2^k} \right\rfloor
\;=\; \sum_{k = (a_t \;+\; 1)}^{a_{[t + 1]}} \dfrac{f(t + 1)}{2^k}.$

For $\;k > a_m, \;f(1) < 2^k \;\Rightarrow\;
\left\lfloor \dfrac{f(1)}{2^k} \right\rfloor \;=\; 0.$

Thus $\displaystyle\;\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \left\lfloor \dfrac{f(1)}{2^k} \right\rfloor $

$\displaystyle=\; \sum_{k=1}^{a_1} \dfrac{f(1)}{2^k} \;+\; 
\sum_{k = (a_1 \;+\; 1)}^{a_2} \dfrac{f(2)}{2^k} \;+\;
\sum_{k = (a_2 \;+\; 1)}^{a_3} \dfrac{f(3)}{2^k} \;+\;
\cdots  \;+\;
\sum_{k = (a_{[m-1]} \;+\; 1)}^{a_m} \dfrac{f(m)}{2^k}$

$\displaystyle=\; \sum_{k=1}^{a_1} \dfrac{2^{a_1}}{2^k} \;+\; 
\sum_{k=1}^{a_2} \dfrac{2^{a_2}}{2^k} \;+\;
\sum_{k=1}^{a_3} \dfrac{2^{a_3}}{2^k} \;+\;
\cdots  \;+\;
\sum_{k=1}^{a_m} \dfrac{2^{a_m}}{2^k}$

$=\;$ [by Lemma 1] 
$\displaystyle\;\left(2^{a_1} \;-\; 1\right) \;+\; 
\left(2^{a_2} \;-\; 1\right) \;+\; 
\left(2^{a_3} \;-\; 1\right) \;+\; 
\cdots \;+\;
\left(2^{a_m} \;-\; 1\right)$ 
$=\; (n - m).$

$\underline{\text{Part 2:  To Prove} 
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \,\left\lfloor \dfrac{n}{2^k}
\;+\; \dfrac{1}{2} \right\rfloor = n}$

For $\;i \,\in \,\mathbb{Z},\;$ define $\;g(i)\;$ so that:
if $\;i \,\in \,\{ \,a_1, \,a_2, \,\cdots, \,a_m \,\}\;$
then $\;g(i) = 1$ 
else $\;g(i) = 0.$

Lemma 2:

$\displaystyle\left\{ \,g(k-1) = 1 \;\Rightarrow\;
\left\lfloor \dfrac{n}{2^k} \;+\; \dfrac{1}{2} \right\rfloor
\;=\; \left\lfloor \dfrac{n}{2^k} \right\rfloor \;+\; 1 \,\right\}\;$ and

$\displaystyle\left\{ \,g(k-1) = 0 \;\Rightarrow\;
\left\lfloor \dfrac{n}{2^k} \;+\; \dfrac{1}{2} \right\rfloor
\;=\; \left\lfloor \dfrac{n}{2^k} \right\rfloor \,\right\}.$

Proof:

$\displaystyle g(k-1) = 1 \;\Rightarrow\;
\dfrac{n}{2^k} \;-\; \left\lfloor \dfrac{n}{2^k}\right\rfloor 
\;\geq\; \dfrac{1}{2}\;$ and

$\displaystyle g(k-1) = 0 \;\Rightarrow\;
\dfrac{n}{2^k} \;-\; \left\lfloor \dfrac{n}{2^k}\right\rfloor 
\;<\; \dfrac{1}{2}.$

.............

Thus, $\displaystyle\; \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}
\left\lfloor \dfrac{n}{2^k} \;+\; \dfrac{1}{2} \right\rfloor$

$\displaystyle =\;
\sum_{k=1}^{a_m \;+\; 1}
\left\lfloor \dfrac{n}{2^k} \;+\; \dfrac{1}{2} \right\rfloor$

$=\;$ [by Lemma 2]
$\;\displaystyle\left(\sum_{k=1}^{a_m \;+\; 1}
\left\lfloor \dfrac{n}{2^k}\right\rfloor\right) \;+\; m$

$=\;$ [by Part 1]
$\;(n - m) \;+\; m \;=\; n.$

Comment: Very nice, thanks for contributing to this conversation! 1) Your approach of $ P(N) \rightarrow P(2N), P(2N+1)$ is how I've usually seen this proved. 2) There is a direct proof of both, which focuses on how much contribution each term gives. That was how I originally approached it, till I discovered the numerical answer, and then rewrote it (explaining the comments on my solution). The main idea is that $ \lfloor \frac{ an + b } { n } \rfloor = a + \lfloor \frac{ b}{ n } \rfloor $. The conversion to binary makes it clear what to set $a, b$ to.